# Why does my TextField change size in the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

This behavior seems new.  I have a very simply User Interface with Auto Layout off.  But when I size my text fields, they appear different in the simulator and I am not sure why.

Sized in the InterfaceBuilder:
[image]

But when I run in iOS simulator
[image]

As far as I can tell I am setting these correctly:
[image]
[image]

This is new - before the latest version of xCode, this sized up as designed in xCode.  Any help is greatly appreciated.